# Posting Video from IOS app to Users Facebook Wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Im very new to Xcode and i'm trying to create a somewhat Social Networking app. At this point i'm not looking for it to be its own app but I want the app to have the ability to let the User sign into their Facebook Account and than Post a Video from the Camera Roll to their wall. I know it sounds simple but Ive look and all i can get are extremely confusing answers that don't make any sense.

Thanks in Advance.

Looking for
1 allow Facebook Login 
2) Post Video from Camera Roll to their facebook.

If possible It would be cool to have a thumbnail of the video before they post it. Kind of like instagram.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to create an app for your `iOS` app on `Facebook`. Then use the tokens or keys they provide you with, in order for your app to be able to do anything with `Facebook`.

`Facebook` has pretty good instructions on how to set up `Facebook` login on your app. You can find detailed, step-by-step instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/). Depending on what type of login you need, you can choose a suitable option.

I have not posted actually files so far onto a Facebook feed/wall. But I *have* set up sharing of posts. You can find instructions for that [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/).

Hope this helps.